# downloading supporting documents from www folder in shiny application

Tags: download, shiny

Since the dataset that drives the app is huge, In my shiny application, I am creating a glossary page.  However, I could not cover all the details.  Some of them I like to provide as downloadable word or pdf files.  Assuming the name of my file is

```
estimates.doc
```

which i have saved in `www` folder of my app, my code within the UI of the app is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- navbarPage("TITLE HERE",
    tabPanel("GLOSSARY",
        p("Click", a(href = "~/www/Estimation_Procedure.doc", "here"), "to download.")
    )
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am not sure how to include the downloadHandler here...i am getting the message "NOT FOUND".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a downloadHandler and downloadLink.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- navbarPage("TITLE HERE",
                 tabPanel("GLOSSARY", 
                          downloadLink(outputId = 'myFile'   , label = 'to download' ) 
                 )
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {  
  output$myFile <- downloadHandler(    
    # generate file name
    filename = function() {     
      'Estimation_Procedure.doc'   
    } , 
    # set file content
    content  = function(file) {  
       file.copy('www/Estimation_Procedure.doc' , file)  
    }
  ) 
} 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```